How do I get rid of these odd ray shaped shadows-- or at least figure out what's causing them?
I'm seeing these really weird shadows all over my mesh in Object and Edit modes and while in the render:

They only appear up close, but I'm worried that there's something I'm doing wrong. Can anyone explain to me what's causing this?

hello, maybe overlapping faces? Could you please share one of these objects?

Do you have Shadows enabled in the 3D Viewport? Try disabling those and see if it fixes it. The Viewport shadow effect struggles with large objects made of a bunch of disconnected elements.

I do have shadows enabled with a bunch of disconnected objects. I'll give that a shot, thanks.

It is a bit of speculation without more detail, however you could try:

selecting ALL in Edit Mode and then Mesh > Merge > Merge by distance.


Then In the lower left an operator panel will appear.

Decrease the accuracy (possibly to 0.1 depending on how large this model is) and see if that helps. Then recalculate normals under Mesh > Normals > Recalculate Outside.
Other actions your could try:

Check the clipping distances on your camera and viewport.

Shut off all scene lights and use an HDRI to see if one of your lights is problematic.

Go into the Render Tab and scroll down to Shadows;  increase the cube and cascade size, and also turn on high bit depth.

Lastly, the scene may simply require higher samples, in the viewport and renders.  Render out one frame at a very high sample rate and see if it persists.



Thanks! I'll try these and get back to you asap.
